# Unity Prefab don't interact with OnTriggerEnter2D method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I tried to make a door logic that works when player use the attack function. Everything seems to be great, and the code works. But attack prefab doesn't interact with OnTriggerEnter2D. However, everything works perfectly when the player enters the collider where the script is assigned(if I changed it for the player to be able to interact). But it doesn't interact when I spawn an attack prefab. Here are two scripts:

**The script that spawns Attack Prefab.**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer RysonState;
    public GameObject AttackRight;
    public GameObject AttackLeft;
    public AudioSource SwooshSound;

    private bool canAttack = true;
    private float attackCooldown = 0.75f;
    private float lastAttackTime = 0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        RysonState = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        if (canAttack && Time.time >= lastAttackTime + attackCooldown)
        {
            if (RysonState.flipX == false)
            {
                Instantiate(AttackLeft, transform.position, Quaternion.identity); //This action creates the clone of the prefab assigned in Inspector.
                SwooshSound.Play();
            }
            else if (RysonState.flipX == true)
            {
                Instantiate(AttackRight, transform.position, Quaternion.identity); //This action creates the clone of the prefab assigned in Inspector.
                SwooshSound.Play();
            }

            lastAttackTime = Time.time;
            StartCoroutine(AttackCooldownCoroutine());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AttackCooldownCoroutine()
    {
        canAttack = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackCooldown);
        canAttack = true;
    }
}
```

**And here is the script doing the door logic:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Gate;
    public AudioSource Beep;
    public GameObject Mark;
    public Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    public float moveDuration = 1.0f;
    private bool isMoving = false;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D terminal)
    {
        if (terminal.gameObject.CompareTag("Attack"))
        {
            if (!isMoving)
            {
                StartCoroutine(MoveCoroutine());
                Beep.Play();
                Mark.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveCoroutine()
    {
        isMoving = true;

        Vector3 startPosition = Gate.position;
        float elapsedTime = 0f;

        while (elapsedTime < moveDuration)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            float t = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / moveDuration);

            Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, targetPosition, t);

            Gate.position = newPosition;

            yield return null;
        }

        Gate.position = targetPosition;

        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

[image: Now, here is the terminal that opens the door in the inspector:]

[image: Second part of the terminal:]

[image: Here is two prefabs in the inspector]

[image: Second part of the prefabs]

Here is the photo took in Inspector for Terminal that opens the door and for Attack prefabs that must interact with BoxCollider. I tried to set IsTrigger but it didn't helped.
Any ideas?